# Record not inserted after publishing in IIS10

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, web-deployment, iis-10

I have developed an asp.net mvc application. I am generating an xml file during registration of new user and displaying and inserting this xml format data in db as a parameter.
Now the problem is when i publish my website in IIS 10 under default website as new application its working but when i deploy new website in root (under site) all things working perfectly except its not inserting data in db.
error comes : "An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details."

I am using stored procedure and passing xml format as a xml parameter.I have checked stored procedure is working fine. Code is working fine during development and if i published under Default website.
why the code is not working if i publish it as a new website ?

Comment: Where is the XML file generated? Does the site has access to the path where you create this file? Also, you should check the inner exception to get more information.

Comment: XML file is generated at under website path and it has the access.